# global definition does not work in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, global-variables, libraries

I have tried to import and define a library globally as below, but somehow it does not recognize the global variable.

in main.js,

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VueJwtDecode from 'vue-jwt-decode'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueJwtDecode)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

in Signup.vue,

```
...
const payload = VueJwtDecode.decode(res.jwt);
...
```

and the error shows that VueJwtDecode is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use the named reference of `VueJwtDecode`, you need to reimport the library in your Signup.vue compoenent since Signup.vue doesn't understand what `VueJwtDecode` means.

```
import VueJwtDecode from 'vue-jwt-decode'
const payload = VueJwtDecode.decode(res.jwt);
```

However, since you have globally installed the library, it has been installed to the Vue instance, meaning that it is available from the `this` context within your component.  As a result, you can also access it from the component context without reimporting:

```
const payload = this.$jwtDec(res.jwt);
```

Answer (score 0):

As [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-jwt-decode), in your component, you need to use

```
this.$jwtDec(res.jwt)
```

instead of

```
VueJwtDecode.decode(res.jwt);
```

Comment: I edit my answer. If you don't understand, can you include full source code of  Signup.vue in your question?